# Sql Server - Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char

Tags: sql, sql-server, newid

I am getting below error when I run sql query while copying data from one table to another,

> Msg 8170, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Insufficient result space to convert
>   uniqueidentifier value to char.

My sql query is,

```
INSERT INTO dbo.cust_info (
uid,
first_name,
last_name
)
SELECT
NEWID(),
first_name,
last_name
FROM dbo.tmp_cust_info
```

My create table scripts are,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cust_info](
    [uid] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [first_name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [last_name] [varchar](100) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp_cust_info](
    [first_name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [last_name] [varchar](100) NULL)
```

I am sure there is some problem with **NEWID()**, if i take out and replace it with some string it is working.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41):

A guid needs 36 characters (because of the dashes). You only provide a 32 character column. Not enough, hence the error.

Comment: And btw, you should use `uniqueidentifier` column type to store guids, not `character(36)` (var is no needed since is not variable, is it?). `uniqueidentifier` only needs 16 bytes for storage, as opposed to 36 needed for the character representation of a guid.

Comment: simple yet straight forward answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use one of 3 alternatives

1, A uniqueidentifier column, which stores it internally as 16 bytes.  When you select from this column, it automatically renders it *for display* using the 8-4-4-4-12 format.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cust_info](
    [uid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [first_name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [last_name] [varchar](100) NULL)
```

2, **not recommended** Change the field to char(36) so that it fits the format, including dashes.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cust_info](
    [uid] char(36) NOT NULL,
    [first_name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [last_name] [varchar](100) NULL)
```

3, **not recommended** Store it without the dashes, as just the 32-character components

```
INSERT INTO dbo.cust_info (
uid,
first_name,
last_name
)
SELECT
replace(NEWID(),'-',''),
first_name,
last_name
FROM dbo.tmp_cust_info
```

Answer (score 6):

I received this error when I was trying to perform simple string concatenation on the GUID.  Apparently a `VARCHAR` is not big enough.

I had to change:

`SET @foo = 'Old GUID: {' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @guid) + '}';`

to:

`SET @foo = 'Old GUID: {' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), @guid) + '}';`

...and all was good.  Huge thanks to the prior answers on this one!

Answer (score 2):

Increase length of your uid column from varchar(32) ->varchar(36)
because guid take 36 characters 
Guid.NewGuid().ToString() -> 36 characters 
outputs: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. This worked for me.

Specify a length for VARCHAR when you cast/convert a value..for uniqueidentifier use VARCHAR(36) as below:

```
SELECT Convert (varchar(36),NEWID()) AS NEWID
```

The default length for VARCHAR datatype if we don't specify a length during CAST/CONVERT is 30..

Credit : Krishnakumar S

Reference : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb24a153-f468-4e18-afb8-60ce90b55234/insufficient-result-space-to-convert-uniqueidentifier-value-to-char?forum=transactsql

Comment: This resolved my issue, I was attempting pass a `@TraceId` parameter into SPROCS to enable information logging if actions were performed without error. Once I updated to varchar(36) my issue was resolved, however initially I had forgotten to update the top level paremeter `@TraceId output`  to varchar(36) as well so it truncated the value initially in my logs. Don't forget to update all the references or you may have unexpected results lol.